# Do scientists generally use their name in their discoveries themselves or does someone else do them the honors?

Tags: science

For example, was the term Newtonian physics coined by Newton himself or by someone else? What about Hamiltonian or Langrangian physics?

Comment: Could you clarify whether you mean historical, contemporary, or both?

Comment: I guess it's more common in engineering. See for example [this](https://doi.org/10.1109/9.121623) and also [this](https://doi.org/10.1115/1.4002697).